# Ajax call to PHP only returns "status 200 OK" but no array with database results?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, pdo

I make an AJAX call to a php file that uses PDO to connect to mysql, and I print the result to the console, but the only result displayed is:

```
Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}
```

The same call works with msqli and the json with the results is displayed, what am i doing wrong?

Here is the code:

custom js:

```
 /*eslint-env jquery, browser*/
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#botono").click(function(){

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'phpf/retraerClientes.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });

 });

});
```

PHP:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);

define('IS_AJAX', isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest'); 
if(!IS_AJAX) {die('');}

$configs = include('config.php');

 try{

$conn = new      PDO("mysql:host=".$configs["host"].";dbname=".$configs["database"],$configs["use    rname"],$configs["password"]);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM prueba";
$results = $conn->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$jsonFinal = json_encode($results);
echo $jsonFinal;

}catch(PDOException $ex){
    echo 'Connection With Database Failed: '.$ex->getMessage();
}
```

UPDATE:
i found the answer:

```
$accents = $conn->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

that line was missing, my records had accents, that made the final json corrupt and created a false positive

Comment: can you post a var_dump for $result

Comment: {readyState: 4, responseText: ""bool(false)↵"", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}

Comment: is that a var_dump in javascript ? i meant in PHP

Comment: sorry, I'm using bluemix and didn't know how to do that properly but i found the answer:
$accents = $conn->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

that line was missing, my records had accents, that made the final json corrupt and created a false positive.

Answer (score 1):

as i seen you'll need to execute the query in PHP:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);

define('IS_AJAX', isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest'); 
if(!IS_AJAX) {die('');}

$configs = include('config.php');

 try{

$conn = new      PDO("mysql:host=".$configs["host"].";dbname=".$configs["database"],$configs["use    rname"],$configs["password"]);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM prueba";
$results = $conn->prepare($sql)->execute()->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$jsonFinal = json_encode($results);
echo $jsonFinal;

}catch(PDOException $ex){
    echo 'Connection With Database Failed: '.$ex->getMessage();
}
```

http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Comment: same result with that method